# Undefined reference when using pointer to undefined member function

Tags: c++

Why does this cause an undefined reference?

```
struct A { void f(); };

int main()
{
    auto f = &A::f;
}
```

Does the function have to be defined before I can get a pointer to it? Why does it cause a linker error?

Update: I just found out that compiling with [no optimizations](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f5d1c01a2fc1daa) gives the undefined reference.

Comment: When you *use* it? This code alone shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: @remyabel When I compile with no optimizations it gives the linker error. Otherwise [it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d08afd3f20ff588e).

Comment: If you enable optimization, the compiler probably optimizes your program all the way down to `int main() { return 0; }`.  That's why the problem seems to go away.

Comment: Anyway, what's the purpose of such code?  Why do you want to take the address of a function that is not defined anywhere?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What is `static` supposed to do? [It doesn't even fix it.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df8c1f0125528bf2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get address to not exist variable. (function, for the matter, is kind of const variable)

What you have now it is just like a forward declaration. You state for a function but not implement it (it is similar to missing `extern` variable).

The address itself should be given during link, but when the linker search for it, it is missing.

In addition the function can be implemented after the main function or even in other file, but the compiler is processing one file at a time in a serial processing. therefor the compiler can't know the function was not implemented anywhere.

So there is no compile error since there is forward declaration, and the name is known, but there is link error because the function is used but not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

It has no implementation so the function does not exist and the linker cannot find it to take its address.  Instead of:

```
struct A { void f(); };
```

Use:

```
struct A { void f() {} };
```